# ALLEXCEPT not working when filtering blanks

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a simple problem. My DAX measure does not seem to be working correctly when I filter for non-existing values. Here are some details:

Table:
Column1: A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B

Column2: 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,5

Measure = calculate(countrows(table), allexcept(column1))

Card Visual returns correct row count when I filter by column1 (any value in filtering pane)

However it returns wrong row count when I filter by column2 = "4" and Column1 = "B" (in filtering pane). It seems that it should ingore filtering by column2 and it does except when I specifically filer for value = "4". It gives "blank" result value in a card visual then.

Any ideas why?

Here's the screen. I would like to populate that blank cell with "4" (in a singe-table data model.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IchCU.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you dont need to add **allexcept** in your measure. Below code would be fine.

```
TestMeasure = countrows(Test_Data)
```

PFB screenshot
[image: strong text]

Comment: Hi, thanks for such a quick response. Please refer to my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that you have a data model as following

table name _dim1

| colA |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

table name _dim2

| colB |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

table name _fact

| colA | colB |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |

[image: DM]

If you have this you can reach where you need by using following measures

```
Measure3 =
CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( _fact ), ALL ( _dim2[colB] ), VALUES ( _fact[colA] ) )

Measure9 =
VAR _1 =
    MAX ( _dim2[colB] )
VAR _2 =
    CALCULATE (
        MAXX (
            FILTER ( _dim2, _dim2[colB] <= _1 ),
            LASTNONBLANKVALUE ( _dim2[colB], [Measure3] )
        ),
        ALL ( _dim2[colB] )
    )
RETURN
    _2
    
Measure10 =
VAR _1 =
    MAX ( _dim2[colB] )
VAR _2 =
    CALCULATE (
        MAXX (
            FILTER ( _dim2, _dim2[colB] > _1 ),
            FIRSTNONBLANKVALUE ( _dim2[colB], [Measure3] )
        ),
        ALL ( _dim2[colB] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( [Measure9] ) = TRUE (), _2, [Measure9] )
```

[image: Solution]

I don't think you can reach here from a single table like following

| colA | colB |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response. It works if i change the model. But I would really like to know why it's not working for a single-table model. Why allexcept does not ignore the filtering where it should? Is there a scientific explanation to that? What if I really need to have a single-table model?

Comment: I just need a simple single measure countrows calculation to show be the result of 4 rows. Even when I use all() function it does not show me results in the matrix visual (shows blanks) for a combination of "B" and "4".